# How can I keep an element on the bottom of the page when keyboard is opened on iOS and android?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a button in a webpage that I want at the bottom of the page. I want this button at the bottom of page no matter where scroll is. The problem is the standard css of `bottom: 0px;position:fixed;` does not work when the keyboard is up.

Right now we are using [ion-footer-bar](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionFooterBar/) but that only keeps the button on top of the keyboard on android. When the keyboard gets pulled up for ios it does not get moved up. Anyone have any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 0):

**For applications using Cordova you can do the following:**

This is due to the fact that on Android the WebView shrinks when the keyboard and on iOS it does not (by default). So iOS is you can put the following code somewhere in the initialization of your app and it should behave the same on iOS as it does on Android.

```
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.shrinkView(false);
```

This function does not work on Android, so you don't have to worry about it there.

Comment: We don't have cordova because we are using a web-app

Comment: So where is the problem occurring? On iOS using Safari? How can I reproduce this problem?